# Leaflet GeoCSV + Lat & Lon coordinates are stored in the same column + how to extract values?

Tags: leaflet, csv

In my CSV file, the Latitude and Longitude coordinates are stored in the same column 'coordinates'.

CSV example:

```
title;status;coordinates
Title1;active;48.08871174971783, -1.6800857423296234
```

Here is my code to render markers:

```
var datas = L.geoCsv(data, {
          firstLineTitles: true,
          fieldSeparator: ';',
          lineSeparator: '\n',
          latitudeTitle: 'coordinates',
          longitudeTitle: 'coordinates',
          debug: true,
          pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {});
          },
...
```

I can't specify/extract the value on latitudeTitle and longitudeTitle params.

If I split data inside the 2 columns Lat and Lng, It' works.

But I do not always master the construction of the CSV file.

I can extract values in new vars :

```
var coordinatesArgs = feature.properties.coordinates.split(',');
return L.marker([coordinatesArgs[0], coordinatesArgs[1]], {});
```

But in my CSV file, I need to keep 2 columns lat and lng...

Comment: What is `data`: reference to a file, string or object?

Comment: data is the variable that stores datas from a csv file. Here is the start code : fetch("assets/datas/csv/myfile.csv").then(response => response.text()).then(data => {...

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a GIS related question, but essentially a pure JS related one, but anyway...

CSV text, loaded with `fetch`, has to be changed/transformed with standard JS functions/methods into desired from. One possible way to do this is to break it into array with `.split` and `.map` methods, modify content and then convert it back to string with `.map` and `.join` methods.

Procedure goes like this:

- convert string to array of lines with `.split('\n')` method;
- convert each line to array of CSV column values with `.split(';')` method;
- iterate through line array and convert last element containing joined coordinates into two elements with `.split(',')` method;
- convert array back to string with `.map` and `.join` methods.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
fetch("assets/datas/csv/myfile.csv").then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
  var parsedContent = data.split('\n').map(e => e.split(';'));
  var lastInd = parsedContent[0].length - 1;
  parsedContent[0][lastInd] = 'lat';
  parsedContent[0][lastInd + 1] = 'lng';
  for (var i = 1; i < parsedContent.length; i++) {
    var coords = parsedContent[i][lastInd].split(',');
    parsedContent[i][lastInd] = coords[0];
    parsedContent[i][lastInd + 1] = coords[1];
  }
  var modifiedData = parsedContent.map(e => e.join(';')).join('\n');
  var datas = L.geoCsv(modifiedData, {
  ...
  ...
});
```